# left aligned boxes don't stay in parent div

Tags: html, css

I have boxes that I want to float left, so they would be aligned side by side. But I have a problem. If I set `float: left;` I get this:
[left aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bII9o.png)

They jump out of parent div (gray div). If I set `float: none;` I get this: [float: none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DltbF.png)

Boxes stay in div, and div stretches with them, but they are one under another, which I don't like. How would i achieve left aligned boxes inside div?
CSS of the boxes:

```
.parent {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(230,230,230);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you have to clear the floats https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: just add  `<div style="clear: both"></div>` at the end inside parent `div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use overflow css rule. In the grey box add following css property:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

After applying this property you will get the items inside grey box and they will not fall outside it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to inside parent div in last.

```
<div class="parent">
    your code
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you use float you need to clear it by assigning `clear: both` to its parent

Comment: nothing happens when i add clear: both to its parent div